# How can I add API key to Apollo-Angular to fetch data from mongodb realm GraphQL API

Tags: angular, mongodb, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-angular

I am using MongoDB realm GraphQL API to access data. I am using Apollo-Angular.

The GraphQL API needs an API key to access the data. I tried with the postman and it work. Using the postman post request I pass the key in the Authorization that added in Header with the key: apiKey,  value: The_Api_Key_from_Mongo

But how can I add this authorization Apollo-Angular settings?

```
const uri =
  'https://ap-south-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/myapp_with_id/graphql'; 

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({
      uri,
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}
```

**Simply**: I have GraphQL api uri to access this API I have to pass api key. How can I do this in Apollo-Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your Apollo Angular return statement by passing this new param to the `HttpLink`. So instead of the `link` key in

```
  return {link: httpLink.create({uri})
```

holds a single object it will hold an array of objects. The new API key can be attached as an item in the array after passing it to the `setContext()` method.

1- Set the new authentication API key using `setContext()`:

```
const authAPIKey = setContext(()=>({headers: new HttpHeaders().set('key', `APIKEY_PLACE_HOLDER`)}))
```

2- Set your URI as another `const` similar to the `APIKey` in step 1 above

```
  const URI = httpLink.create({uri})
```

3- Refactor your return statement to be

```
return {
    link: from([authAPIKey, URI]),
    cache: cache,
  };
```

4- Do not forget to import `from` in the return statement above from `'@apollo/client/core'` and `setContext()` from `'@apollo/client/link/context'`

Comment: ``const uri =
  'https://ap-south-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/myapp_with_id/graphql';

const authAPIKey = setContext(() => ({
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('key', key),
}));

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  return {
    link: from([
      authAPIKey,
      httpLink.create({
        uri,
      }),
    ]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}``


Showing this error: https://ibb.co/ykssZ6x

Comment: you have a Cross Origin Ressource Sharing Error. Check your server authorization configuration